# Is there a way I can validate YAML files on Github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, validation, github, yaml

I am currently working on a Ruby on Rails App. I have a directory filled with different Yaml File that gets edited from time to time. Anytime a Developer accidentally merge with invalid Yaml syntax to the Main branch. The entire Application breaks.

Is there anyway i can setup a Yaml Validator on Github that checks for validity of my Yaml files in a specific directory in my Repo and stop a PR from being merged into Main if this Yaml Validator check fails?

Comment: Hi @samlexxy how about using the following action
https://github.com/nrkno/yaml-schema-validator-github-action

Answer (score 4):

You can use a YAML linter in a [GitHub Action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) that runs for every pull request. [`yamllint`](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) is already installed on Ubuntu-based GitHub runners according to the [docs](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#tools).

Here is a basic workflow:

```
name: Validate-YAML

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  validate-yaml:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Validate YAML file
        run: yamllint abc.yml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Matt . Let's say i wanted to target all the yaml files in a directory in the Repo called **stores**

can i have `run` as

`run: yamllint stores/.` 
or 
`run: yamllint stores/*.yaml`

Comment: @samlexxy The [documentation](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#running-yamllint) shows how to to scan a whole directory and how to configure which files to take into account or exclude.

Answer (score 3):

**A more generic approach without using Github Hooks**.

One option, which I currently use, is [overcommit](https://github.com/sds/overcommit). It has a lot of hooks that can be executed before a `git commit` (amongst others).

For your scenario, this should work.

```
YamlSyntax:
   enabled: true
   description: 'Check YAML syntax'
   required_library: 'yaml'
   include:
     - '**/*.yaml'
     - '**/*.yml'
```

Here's a list of those hooks: https://github.com/sds/overcommit/blob/master/config/default.yml.

You can add rubocop, sorbet, etc. This will only work if the entire team has it installed, otherwise those who have it will most likely need to fix things left out by the other team members.

Comment: I was expecting to see github-only approach answers. This is a more general approach with commit hooks.

Comment: You are right. Let me update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using JSON Schema to validate the content of the YAML files. (A linter like yamllint checks if the YAML syntax is correct and follows best practices - not if the data is in the expected form).

Nowadays there are many tools in different languages that can validate the content of YAML files with JSON Schema.

Two examples that I have used in the past:

- [ajv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-cli)
- [yajsv](https://github.com/neilpa/yajsv)

There are also tools for generating JSON schemas, or if your YAML is simple, you can just write it by hand.

With this approach, you can ensure that the YAML in your RP is valid and that the data is written in the correct format. As a bonus, you can provide syntax highlighting and validation to the developer directly in the IDE with a YAML extension based on the YAML Language Server.

I wrote a blog post where I describe everything in detail. [YAML Data Validation](https://infrastructureascode.ch/yaml_validation.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VSCode for development, you could get the Yaml extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml

It validates YAML syntax, highlighting any errors as well as providing auto-complete.

Answer (score 0):

One way we used for yaml validation is to convert Yaml to Hash and apply dry-schema validation on that hash https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-schema/

Answer (score 0):

I created a GitHub Action to solve this **exact** issue for both yaml and json files

https://github.com/GrantBirki/json-yaml-validate

---

Here is a sample GitHub Actions workflow which will validate all JSON and YAML files in your repository to ensure they are syntactically correct:

```yaml
name: json-yaml-validate 
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  json-yaml-validate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: json-yaml-validate
        id: json-yaml-validate
        uses: GrantBirki/json-yaml-validate@vX.X.X # replace with the latest version
```